# Is it possible to keep executing test if element wasn't found with Cypress

Tags: cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

I have a case when I need to wait for element (advertising), if it's visible then needs to click it, but if element wasn't found after timeout then needs to keep executing a test.

How to handle the situation with Cypress ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I tried the above solution, but seems that in some cases parameter `$body` could not contain necessary element, cause it was not loaded when we invoked `cy.get('body')`. So, I found another solution, using jQuery via Cypress, here is it:

```
let counter = 0;
const timeOut: number = Cypress.config('defaultCommandTimeout');
  
  const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
  };

  while (true) {
    if (Cypress.$(element).length > 0 && Cypress.$(element).is(':visible')) {
      Cypress.$(element).click();
      break;
    } else {
      sleep(500);
      counter = counter + 500;
        if (counter >= timeOut) {
          cy.log(elementName+ ' was not found after timeout');
          break;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: sleep function is pointless, use built-in `cy.wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

The way Cypress says to check for a conditional element is [Element existence](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Element-existence)

```js
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
  const modal = $body.find('modal')
  if (modal.length) {
    modal.click()
  }
})
```

Most likely you put that at the top of the test, and it runs too soon (there's no retry timeoout).

You can add a wait say 30 seconds, but the test is delayed every time.

Better to call recursively

```js
const clickModal = (selector, attempt = 0) => {

  if (attempt === 100) return  // whole 30 seconds is up

  cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
    const modal = $body.find('modal')
    if (!modal.length) {
      cy.wait(300)  // wait in small chunks
      clickModal(selector, ++attempt)
    }
  })
  return             // done, exit
}

cy.get('body')
  .then($body => clickModal('modal'))
```

---

#### Intercept the advert

Best is if you can find the url for the advert in network tab, use `cy.intercept()` to catch it and stub it out to stop the modal displaying.